# avoid for loops when multiple tasks and/or if statements are in involved

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a large data.frame with thousands of lines, on which I am looping each time creating a subset from line 1 up to incrementally one additional line per iteration.

On each subset I perform several tasks which, coming from a pythonic understanding of programming, I carry out with 'for' loops. E.g.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1:10), b=c(11:20), c=c(21:30), d=c(31:40))
for (index in 1:nrow(df)) {
  thisSubset <- df[1: index,] 

  #loop 1  
  new1 <- ncumeric(nrow(thisSubset))
  for (i in 1:nrow(thisSubset)) {              
         var1 = 5 - thisSubset$b[i]        
         new1[i] <- 1/exp(var1*log(2));
  }
  #loop 2         
  new2 <- numeric()
  for (i in 1:nrow(thisSubset)) if (thisSubset$c[i] >25) {
    new2<- c(new2, (thisSubset$a[i]/exp(5*log(2))))
  } 
  #loop 3  
  new3 <- numeric(nrow(thisSubset)) 
  for (i in 1:nrow(thisSubset)) if (thisSubset$a[i] < 5) {
      new3[i] <- thisSubset$d[i]-thisSubset$d[i+1]/2
  } else {
    new3[i] <- thisSubset$d[i]-thisSubset$d[i-1]/2 
    }
  #loop x
  #... 
}
```

As my datasets grow larger, processing time increases exponentially to a few hours. I appreciate there are preferable ways of working in R to perform similar tasks (e.g. apply), but can I still use anything other than 'for' when several things are happening in each loop and also when multiple elements of each line are used? I would appreciate if someone could give me an example with each or any of the loops presented above.

Comment: You might benefit from looking at the documentation of the data.table package.  That provides easy subsetting and manipulation (once you get over the initial syntax learning curve).

Comment: Generally, try to move all computations that are "vectorized" before any loop. E.g. no need to to iterate over each `thisSubset$b[i]` to subtract it from 5 as, also, you could save a variable `5 - df$b` before even your outer loop to avoid multiple subtractions. Specfically, the equivalent "vectorised" code to replace your 3 loops is: (1) `new1 = 1 / exp((5 - thisSubset$b) * log(2))`, (2) `new2 = thisSubset$a[thisSubset$c > 25] / exp(5 * log(2))` and, (3) `new3 = ifelse(thisSubset$a < 5, thisSubset$d - c(thisSubset$d[-1], NA) / 2, thisSubset$d - c(NA, thisSubset$d[-nrow(thisSubset)]) / 2)`

Comment: Could you please explain how it works and `c(thisSubset$d[-1], NA)` is equivalent to `thisSubset$d[i+1]` as well as `c(NA, thisSubset$d[-nrow(thisSubset)])` equivalent to `thisSubset$d[i-1]` ? Thanks

Comment: `@alexis_laz` (sorry, forgot to mention you in my comment above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R is a vectorized language and thus most functions can be applied to the entire column in a single statement without iterating down each row.  For example I vectorized your three inner loops:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1:10), b=c(11:20), c=c(21:30), d=c(31:40))

 thisSubset <- df

  #loop 1  
  new1 <- numeric(nrow(thisSubset))
    var1 = 5 - thisSubset$b       
    new1 <- 1/exp(var1*log(2));

  #loop 2         
  new2 <- numeric()
  new2<-  (thisSubset$a[thisSubset$c >25]/exp(5*log(2)))

  #loop 3  
  new3 <- numeric(nrow(thisSubset)) 
  dplus1 <-c(thisSubset$d[-1], thisSubset$d[length(thisSubset$d)])
  dminus1 <-c(thisSubset$d[1], thisSubset$d[-length(thisSubset$d)])
  new3<- ifelse((thisSubset$a < 5), thisSubset$d-dplus1/2, thisSubset$d-dminus1/2)
  #loop x
  #...
```

Your outer loop was unnecessary.
See Mark's solution for additional comments.

Comment: When values are assigned to vectors by means of vectorised statements rather than loops, is @MarkTimms '  recommendation about pre-allocation still the way to go? For example,  in loops 1 and 3 (as in loop 2 it's mis-implemented), do we still benefit from:  `new1 <- numeric(nrow(thisSubset))`

Comment: Yes, it is generally faster to assign a value to a preallocated vector then to continuous add additional elements.

Answer (score 1):

For loops aren't really any slower than their *apply cousins (in fact, sometimes they can even be faster!). The real speed gains come from converting explicit for loops into vectorized code whenever possible. For example, loop 1 and loop 2 in your code can be converted to vectorized statements like so:

```
#loop 1 
new1 <- 1 / exp((5 - thisSubset$b) * log(2))

#loop 2         
new2 <- thisSubset$a[thisSubset$c > 25] / exp(5 * log(2))
```

Things get a little trickier to vectorize when your computations depend on the index of the vector (such as in loop 3), but there do exist packages with efficient implementations of various "rolling" functions (see the `roll` and `zoo` packages for details).

When you do need to use for loops, keep in mind that you should always pre-allocate your "results" vector before beginning iteration rather than growing it during iteration:

```
#bad
new2 <- numeric()
for (i in 1:nrow(thisSubset)) {
  if (thisSubset$c[i] >25) {
    new2<- c(new2, (thisSubset$a[i]/exp(5*log(2))))
  }
} 

#good
new2 <- numeric(length = nrow(thisSubset))
for (i in 1:nrow(thisSubset)) {
  if (thisSubset$c[i] >25) {
    new2[i] <- (thisSubset$a[i]/exp(5*log(2)))
  }
}
```

This prevents R from having to copy `new2` after every iteration and results in much faster code.

Comment: `*apply` functions aren't some magic bullet that turns any function into a faster totally vectorized one, but there is a speed up that can be gained from them.  While `*apply` functions are for loops in disguise, the looping for `*apply` happens in `C` rather than `R` and `C` is a much faster language.  If the function you are calling is computationally intensive, you might not see a speed up switching from `for` to `*apply` since the amount of time spent in the actual loop is small.  If the function is quick though, it can make a huge difference.